# Labeling features with font dependent on polygon area?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, labeling

i want to label my island data with variety of size of text based on  the island area for example island that have more than 100km, i want to label it using Arial 12 while island less than 100km i want to label using Arial 10..im label it using maplex.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your area field is called **Shape_Area** (in Square Kilometres) and your label field is called **name**, I would:

1. Open the **Labels** tab of the **Layer Properties**
2. Check the **Advanced** box
3. Set the Parser to **Python**
4. Write a **FindLabel function** for the **Expression** as below – note that it may not Verify correctly but will still work:

> ```
> def FindLabel ( [name], [Shape_Area] ):
>     if float([Shape_Area]) >= 100000:
>         return "<FNT name='Arial' size = '12'>" + [name] + "</FNT>"
>     else:
>         return "<FNT name='Arial' size = '10'>" + [name] + "</FNT>"
> ```

Comment: This is the way that I'd do it, not adding fields to the table or modifying the data, sometimes that's just not possible in an enterprise environment... it's also much quicker to modify a label expression than to re-calculate all your fields.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, i used ArcGIS 10.2 version,and i have try the expression and its work...thank you so much for helping me settle this problem..

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not specific to maplex rather just using the general label properties.  Here are the general steps:

1. Create column to hold area value and calculate geometry area to it
2. Setup the various label classes within the layer properties>labeling tab and define font size, color..etc
3. Set an SQL query for each class by area range

Comment: artwork21 is correct. I'd add, if not clear from that answer, skip maplex in this case. Maplex has great options when you need them (you don't, by your question), but can dramatically slow display time.

Comment: @recurvata I have actually seen Maplex label faster than Standard in some scenarios.  Certainly, I would have agreed in earlier versions, but I now use Maplex as my default, and have not recently seen a need to switch back to Standard for performance reasons.

Comment: Really? That would be good news. What version are you using? I've been going out to get some tea, chat with co-workers, etc., while Maplex ran.